# Creating google_logging_project_sink in Terraform doesn't push events to Pub/Sub

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-pubsub, stackdriver

I want to create a Log Sink to listen to a specific message in Stack Driver and push the event to a Cloud Pub/Sub, which will trigger a Cloud Function.

Here is a part of my Terraform template.

```
resource "google_pubsub_topic" "dataflow_events" {
  name = join("-", concat(["dataflow-events", var.environment, terraform.workspace]))
}

resource "google_logging_project_sink" "dataflow_job_completion_sink" {
  name = join("-", concat(["dataflow-job-completion-sink", var.environment, terraform.workspace]))
  destination = "pubsub.googleapis.com/projects/${var.project}/topics/${google_pubsub_topic.dataflow_events.name}"
  filter = "resource.type=dataflow_step AND textPayload=\"Worker pool stopped.\""
}
```

Terraform version = **0.13.3**

This gets deployed without any errors. However, no events are pushed to the Pub/Sub topic.

However, when I create the sink manually (from the Cloud Web Console), it pushes messages to the (same) Pub/Sub topic.

Here are two screenshots of two sinks.

[image]
[image]

**Note**: Changing `unique_writer_identity` parameter (either `true` or `false`) on both of them doesn't change its behavior. We used `unique_writer_identity` as `true` when we created the manual sink and that's why it has a global service account. But setting this to `true` in Terraform doesn't push messages to Pub/Sub.

Your expertise is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me answer my own question here.
Thanks, [@milindu-sanoj-kumarage](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1190184/milindu-sanoj-kumarage) for the tip.

When we create the Log Sink, it gives a service account that is bound to it.

If you have marked `unique_writer_identity` as `true`, it will look like `[GENERATED_ID_1]@[GENERATED_ID_2].iam.gserviceaccount.com` and it will be `serviceAccount:cloud-logs@system.gserviceaccount.com` if it's set to `false`.

These are global (reside outside your projects) SAs if you haven't already added to your project.

You need to add (derrive) this service account into your GCP project and give permission to write to the destination.

- Go to IAM in the IAM & Admin section --> click on Add button.
- In the **New members** textbox, type `cloud-logs@system.gserviceaccount.com`.
- Select the Roles you need to add. It was Pub/Sub > Pub/Sub Publisher in this case.
- Add a condition to allow only a given Pub/Sub (optional)
- Click on Save

**UPDATE:**
If your organization restricts adding `cloud-logs@system.gserviceaccount.com`, you should have the `unique_writer_identity = true` in your terraform, and then add the unique IAM generated in the IAM window. You can extract this IAM from the Cloud Sink (Log Router) window in the Logging section.

Now, the sink has permission to push events to Pub/Sub. So, whenever it gets out filter text on the logs, it will push it to the given Pub/Sub topic.